# What is the meaning/purpose of コ in ちょっとイケないコになっちゃう

Tags: usage

This is a line in the song lyrics of [「10月のクリスマス」](http://www.evesta.jp/lyric/artists/a9758/lyrics/l135213.html).

I think the basic meaning of this line is:

> Finally becoming somewhat hopeless.

My main question is what is the meaning or purpose of コ here? It does not seem to attach to an adjacent element (イケない and particle に).
By itself, other than 子 somehow, I have no idea what it is for.

Comment: I'm fairly certain it is 子, and ～てしまう（～ちゃう）here is to be interpreted 'regretfully'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answered your own question.

It is こ/コ/子{こ}/娘{こ}, etc.　In this particular context, it means a "girl".

「ちょっとイケない**コ**になっちゃう」 means "I become a slightly 'bad' girl."